# How to import window manager in linux base iso file

Tags: window-manager, slitaz

I downloaded Slitaz 4.0 base but i want to customize it a little with spectrwm window mamager. My question is how i can mount the manager inside the iso and then burn in on DVD or make a bootable drive to install it directly without the need of using git.